# Android list view to display unique values from xml source

Tags: android, xml, listview

For an Android applicaton, I am getting data from an XML source like below:

```
<item>
     <description>product description A </description>
     <category>categoryA</category>
</item>
<item>
     <description>product description B </description>
     <category>categoryB</category>
</item>
```

I want to show all the category values in a list view.  When user clicks on one category, show all description values for that category.

For this, I need to extract all category values, remove the duplications, sort them in alphabetical order and use in a List View.  What is the simplest way of doing it?  If I write my own functions, it goes into so many loops. Any simpler way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use a sax parser to retrieve each element and putting into a HashMap so no duplicate Key values are allowed, then you can use that Map to populate your list.

If you want to filter by category, an interesting option is to populate a db in your app with the parsed data so you can use Cursor to filter,search and query :)

An example of [Sax Parser](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example)

Answer (score 0):

The simpler way to `"remove the duplications"`

```
ArrayList<String> entries;
entries=new ArrayList<String>();
if(!entries.contains("this entry")){
entries.add("this entry");
}
```